ReferenceError: Response is not defined createEvent
ReferenceError: Response is not defined createEvent
というエラーが出ました、４行目
const itemResponses = Response.getItemResponses();
と５行目
for (const itemResponse of itemResponses) {
に問題がありそうなのですが、
どう対処したらいいのかわかりません。
わかる方教えてください。
Googleフォームで入力しスプレッドシートに回答が出たものをベースにGoogleカレンダーへ予定を作成したいです。
対象のフォームはこちらです
https://forms.gle/GnUmqxmnnUu6gkjn9
function createEvent() {

const items = [];
`const itemResponses = Response.getItemResponses();`
for (const itemResponse of itemResponses) {
items.push(itemResponse.getResponse());
}
let id = '71747528af39988701578cb38574f3ec0bb76e65caced921e08a2fedb38e0d4f@group.calendar.google.com';
let calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id);

let [title, date, startTimes, endTimes,] = items;

  const name = '勤務入力（仮）（回答）';
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == name) {
      const values = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn())
      .getDisplayValues()//画面表示の値を文字列として取得
      .flat();//一次元配列に変換


    let yyyy = Number(date.split('/')[0]);
    let mm = Number(date.split('/')[1]);
    let dd = Number(date.split('/')[2]);
    let hoursS = Number(startTimes.split(':')[0]);
    let minutesS = Number(startTimes.split(':')[1]);
    let hoursE = Number(endTimes.split(':')[0]);
    let minutesE = Number(endTimes.split(':')[1]);

    let title = values[1];
    let Date = values[2];
    let startTimes = new Date (values[3]);
    let endTimes = new Date (values[4]);

calendar.createEvent(title, date, startTimes, endTimes);
  }
}


他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿 をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？
